# AWS Postgres RDS Disk Spikes, randomly going down to 0

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

[image]

We have run out of possible answers for this, initially we thought this was due to MVCC and vacuum, but our table sizes are < 10 GB, and there are < 20 tables.